# How can I manage the "Team goals" list?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

The "Team goals" list appears in the top right-hand part of Teams. I was wondering if this is a customizable component? I.e. is there a way to add more goals?

There is no mention of any specific UI customizations in the "Settings" part of Teams (as Admin).

[image: team_goals]

Comment: Whist this sounds like a good idea, we need to be careful not to try to make SO Teams our one stop shop for managing and collaborating as a team. What specific goals are you interested in adding?

Comment: I'm not on the team but have used it enough to say this is not currently possible.  The list is just to get you moving to create your own community with your team.  They want to ensure everyone uses the tool correctly and that everyone knows how to use the tool efficiently.  In order to do so you have to meet the goals.  You cannot add more items to this list, its what you see is what you get.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not on the team but have used it enough to say this is not currently possible. The list is just to get you moving to create your own community with your team. They want to ensure everyone uses the tool correctly and that everyone knows how to use the tool efficiently. In order to do so you have to meet the goals. You cannot add more items to this list, its what you see is what you get. — [JonH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168703/jonh) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/621061)

So, it is not possible to customize this list and that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I'm curious why this post was downvoted. It's ambiguous whether this post was downvoted because the voter thought the post is wrong, or [didn't like someone reposting the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins).